# In which memory section files from assets folders get stored?

Tags: android, performance, android-memory

My android app contains a file which is stored in `assets` folder. I need to know where it gets stored? E.g. Before invoking file reading code.

[image]

As per my understanding, there are 4 memory section so where this file gets stored out of these 4? Or does it get stored on local storage of device before invoking file reading code?

Comment: *I need to know where it gets stored?* - what for

Comment: just by default they are not loaded in memory at all. After that they are being read into heap same way as any other files

Comment: @TimCastelijns Preloading into code where it resides? Need to understand to make my app memory efficient

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Can you please share some reference article?

Comment: It doesn't need any special article. Treat them same as any other files.

Comment: Okay understood. Just good to have them to explore in depth.